# I can't seem to get RadioButtons to work within JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I can't seem to get this block of code to work for RadioButtons. It keeps on giving me an error for the new ChangeListener, the error being "The type ChangeListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments ". However I can't find any examples which isn't like mine below.

```
group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
        if (patrolBut.isSelected()) {
            placeShipVert(patrolBoat, r, playerBoard, shapes);
        } else if (destroyerBut.isSelected()) {
            placeShipVert(destroyer, r, playerBoard, shapes);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the JavaFX `ChangeListener`? There is another `ChangeListener` defined in the Swing API that is not generic (in addition to not compatible).

Comment: I've tried both but the error persists. There's an additional error under "ObservableValue" when using javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener.

Comment: The error for it is "ObservableValue cannot be resolved to a type", I can't see any other way in which a I would call the method.

Comment: Have you imported `ObservableValue`? Also, consider using a lambda expression, as in the answer: `addListener((ov, oldToggle, newToggle) -> { ... });` Then you don't need to import any of these :).

Comment: You're right, hadn't imported ObservableValue, thanks for the help I feel stupid now haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in the comment above, have you imported the correct `ChangeListener`? Depending on your IDE (e.g. Eclipse) you can set your errors and warnings on having to add a @Override annotation to your methods if they override a method. As you think you will have overriden a method (and thus added  a @Override) the IDE would have warned you that in fact you didn't.

If you use Java 8, I personally use change listeners as a Lambda: `foo.addListener( (v, o, n) -> handleNewValue(n));`